# Im trying to extract specific words from txt file with an String input for java

Tags: java

So far:

I scanned a `.txt` file which includes words such as `("monster, lobster, chopper")`

If I used a `scanner` class input `//for my input I would like to input "er"`

how would I be able to print the words in the `.txt` that include `"er"`?

Comment: Please take the time to read the Stack Overflow [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help), paying special attention to the section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions which will receive good answers. Right now, you seem to be making a request for free code, which we don't do here. If, however, you post your existing code. someone may help you modify what you already have. This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `string.Contains("er")` to check if the word matches your pattern or not

Comment: Don't you think `String.endsWith()` would be a much better solution? `String.contains()` will choke on words like "ergo" and "terror". Also, your code has a typographical error in it. That will not compile.

Comment: Would it be like this 'file.endsWith(string))'    Thank you for responding

Comment: no, you will have to do it for every string in the file

Comment: Thank you. i will try this.